# C++ Display unique date and its related price found in txt file

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

Currently I have a system that will store user input in a text file, and a function that will compute the daily sales of the current month and display the sales of the day and the grand total of that month.

For example, here is some text file data for April:

```
1|Bag|2|3|6|20Apr2015
2|File|2.3|5|11.5|20Apr2015
3|File|2.3|5|15.5|20Apr2015
4|Book|0.9|5|4.5|22Apr2015
5|Pencil|0.9|5|4.5|25Apr2015
6|Ruler|0.9|5|4.5|20Jul2015
7|Eraser|0.9|5|4.5|20Jul2015
8|Bag|0.9|5|4.5|28Apr2015
9|File|0.9|5|4.5|20Apr2015
```

Here is my current output:

```
20Apr2015 $11.5
20Apr2015 $15.5
22Apr2015 $4.5
25Apr2015 $4.5
28Apr2015 $4.5
20Apr2015 $4.5
     Grand Total $45
```

But my desired result should be like this:

```
20Apr2015 $31.5
22Apr2015 $4.5
25Apr2015 $4.5
28Apr2015 $4.5
     Grand Total $45
```

It should combine all sales of each day.

Below is my code to compute the Daily Sales. Can anyone guide me on how to get my desired output?

```
struct TransactionPile
{
  // to record item information.
  string itemid;
  string itemdesc;
  float unitprice;
  int quantity;
  float totalprice;
  string date;
  time_t now = time(0);
};

//Function to calculate daily sales
void computeDailySales()
{
  // current date/time based on current system
  time_t now = time(0);
  // convert now to string form
  char* ct = ctime(&now);
  // convert now to tm struct for UTC
  tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
  char* dt = asctime(ltm);

  string itemid;
  float totalprice;
  float totalsales = 0;
  string date;
  int year;
  int month;
  int day;
  int found;
  string syear;
  string smonth;
  string sday;
  string sdate;

  //Get the value of year
  year = (1900 + ltm->tm_year); 
  //Convert the year to string and store into syear
  syear = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << year) )->str();

  //Get the value of month
  month = (1 + ltm->tm_mon);
  //Convert the month to string and store into smonth
  smonth =static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << month) )->str();

  //Get the value of day
  day = ltm->tm_mday;
  //Convert the day to string and store into sday
  sday = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << day) )->str();

  //Store the different month name in smonth if condition met
  if (smonth =="1")
  {
    smonth ="Jan";
  }
  if (smonth =="2")
  {
    smonth ="Feb";
  }
  if (smonth =="3")
  {
    smonth ="Mar";
  }
  if (smonth =="4")
  {
    smonth ="Apr";
  }
  if (smonth =="5")
  {
    smonth ="May";
  }
  if (smonth =="6")
  {
    smonth ="Jun";
  }
  if (smonth =="7")
  {
    smonth ="Jul";
  }
  if (smonth =="8")
  {
    smonth ="Aug";
  }
  if (smonth =="9")
  {
    smonth ="Sep";
  }
  if (smonth =="10")
  {
    smonth ="Oct";
  }
  if (smonth =="11")
  {
    smonth ="Nov";
  }
  if (smonth =="12")
  {
    smonth ="Dec";
  }
  //Concatenate the sday, smonth, syear and store inside sdate
  sdate = sday + smonth + syear;    

  cout<<endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < MAX- 1; i++)
  {
    if(transactionpile[i].itemid !="")
    {
      //Find all related record according to the value in smonth
      found = transactionpile[i].date.find(smonth);
      if(found<transactionpile[i].date.length())
      {
        std::sort(transactionpile.begin(),transactionpile.end(), 
          [](TransactionPile a, TransactionPile b)
               {return a.rawdate<b.rawdate;});

        if(i<MAX-2&&transactionpile[i].date==transactionpile[i+1].date)
        {
          transactionpile[i+1].totalprice+=transactionpile[i].totalprice;
          continue;
        }
        //Add the totalprice of each found records to totalsalesmonth[k]
        totalsales += transactionpile[i].totalprice;
      }
    }
  }

  //Print out the total sales made on the day itself by system date
  cout << "            " << "Total Sale" << endl;
  cout << "            " << totalsales <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have edited your question slightly. In the code section I have replaced the tabs with spaces and adjusted the indentation to make the code easier to read (and to copy & paste). I have made some corrections to English. (We understand that you are not a native English speaker and we do not expect perfection, but these corrections make the text easier to read and understand.) I have rearranged the data and output sections to reflect the logic: data --> output.

Answer (score 0):

Before you output your `transactionpile`, sort the list with the date.

If you want to get a nice sorting (and so that the output list will be in order) keep the `time_t` value in your structure. Now let's say that this new value will be stored in the `rawdate` field. For sorting you could use this:

```
#include <algorithm>
...
std::sort(transactionpile.begin(),transactionpile.end(), 
    [](TransactionPile a, TransactionPile b){return a.rawdate<b.rawdate;}
    /*lambda function: required because std::sort doesn't know how to sort a TransactionPile
);
```

After you just need to change a little bit the code of your output code by adding this:

```
if(i<MAX-2&&transactionpile[i].date==transactionpile[i+1].date){
    transactionpile[i+1].totalprice+=transactionpile[i].totalprice;
    continue; //goes to the next iteration (merge with the current one before printing)
}
```

That way you since your list is sorted you will eliminate duplicates and get the good value in the end. It's probably not the cleanest solution for this but it gets the job done and doesn't add too many lines to the code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking time to answer my queries, need to check with you, since my date that store inside the transactionpile is of string type, i would not be able to compare the string type using arithmetic operator like > or <. In that case, how do i do the sorting? Please assist to advice. I have include a sort function in my previous code.

Comment: Depends what you want to do exactly: if you don't care about the order the comparison on strings will work for finding duplicates. As for a good sorting, you do have the date in a better form (like `time_t`) before you put it in a string. Can't you also store this in your struct?

Comment: For sorting you can use the library functions. I would recommend you to use `std::sort` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) since you can define your own comparison with a lambda function for example. In this case the function would be `[](TransactionPile a, TransactionPile b){return a.date<b.date;}` for example. I'm assuming you can easily get an iterator on `transactionpile`; since you didn't show the type, I assumed it was a `std::vector<TransactionPile>`

Comment: Hi Meneldal, yup, i can store the time_t in my structure, so in this case, in my structure, i will need to have year, month and day instead of just date right? i am quite new to c++, hence the question i asked are abit weird.

Comment: I saw the example that you provided for the std::sort, in the example, there is an array that contain value that are to be sorted, in that context, for mine, i have to store the day value in that array?

Comment: The `time_t` value contains enough information for sorting so you don't have to store years, months and days as well. Basically for `std::sort`, you either use a type for which there is already a comparison operator (like with `std::string` or `int`) or you have to provide your own function. Since `std::sort` doesn't know how to compare a `TransactionPile`, you have to give it a function for that. I'm editing my answer for the full code.

Comment: So by storing the time_t in my structure, i still have to include that whole chunk of code for the date in my function right? In order to call the transactionpile[i].date. Then i have to include the std::sort in my loop of my function? I have edited my code to include the code you provided.

Comment: I don't really follow your code anymore because I can't see where you're starting and ending your functions. You just need to put the code in my answer for sorting before the output loop. The other condition should be just before you output the each line of sales. Maybe you should revert your edit because your code only got more confusing.

Comment: Hi, when you mentioned the "other condition should be just before you output each line of sales", what condition do you meant? So the sorting should come before my for loop right?

Comment: The other condition is `if(i<MAX-2&&transactionpile[i].date==transactionpile[i+1].date)` it should be inside the loop where you go through each transaction so you can skip the ones that happen on the same day. The sorting has to happen before the loop for the condition to be of any use.

Comment: Okay, now i understand, will see if it works, thanks alot for your help on this.

Comment: May i know from your previous comment, you mentioned about " I'm assuming you can easily get an iterator on transactionpile; since you didn't show the type, I assumed it was a std::vector<TransactionPile>", what does this meant?

Comment: `transactionpile` is an array of some sort. Unfortunately, you didn't precise what kind of array you actually used for it. I just assumed it was a `std::vector` because it is common to use this in C++

Comment: Hi, i have tried to add in the code, but seem like my compiler said lambda expression only available with std=c++11 -std=gnu++11

Comment: And when you mentioned about the raw date, what variable do you meant?

Comment: You put the c++11  tag on your question so next time please put the tags correctly. So either you use the flag like the compiler tells you or you create a new function that does exactly the same and pass this as a parameter instead.

Comment: for the raw date I meant the `time_t` you get before converting the information into a string.